# Raspberry Pi won't fully download deb file

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I am working on downloading some software a collaborator of my team at work made onto a raspberry pi but for some reason I am having some trouble. This is the first time I have worked this Raspberry Pis so it is possible that I am doing something sort of silly.

I am trying to install a deb file onto the pi, I navigate to the folder it in the through the terminal and use: `sudo dpkg -i Collaborator_File.deb` to try and install. (I was trying the same with without sudo and was told the "requested operation requires superuser privilege").

After doing this is looks like it is going to install but it doesn't seem to, a few lines pop up on the terminal, I am not prompted for a password or anything, and then it goes back to the command line. The picture below is the terminal read out.

[image: Terminal_readout]

It doesn't appear to be installed, but there also is no error about it not being able to be installed, so I don't really know what is happening. Any guidance would be appreciated! Also I am running Raspbian on the pi, I am not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: The output looks like it did indeed install correctly; perhaps you could [edit] to clarify exactly why it doesn't look like it installed, so we can rule other issues out?

Comment: The question is misleading - the file seems to be downloaded and correctly installed. As we don't know what is supposed to do you will have to ask the author.

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot it looks like at least dpkg is satisfied with the installation process. What makes you think it didn't install correctly?

You can check the result of the command you executed last by executing `echo $?`. If it returns 0, the previous command executed successfully. Any number other than 0 means there was an error.

If you think that you packages was only partially installed, check the [man page for dpkg](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg). You can use the `--audit` switch to get recommendations about what to do about partially installed packages.